# Getting unique rows of a table and their numbers

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
id  y   z
oX  79  100
oX  23  46
oX  10  29
uM  12  90
uT  43  50
uT  13  99
```

I would like to keeep unique rows based on "id", and also keep track of the original number of each id as follows:

```
oX:3
uM:1
uT:2
```

I konw that I can use either unique()/duplicated() for the first part, but unsure about how to keep record the original number of each unique row
How can i do this? Thanks

Comment: Why not just `table` as in `table(mydf$id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will do what you want :

```
> as.data.frame(table(a$id))
  Var1 Freq
1   oX    3
2   uM    1
3   uT    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf", `table` should work just fine:

```
table(mydf$id)
#
# oX uM uT 
#  3  1  2
```

Comment: +1! maybe you should wrap with something like as.data.frame(table(..)) to get the OP output.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to post another alternative, consider `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> data.table(mydf)[,.N, by="id"]
   id N
1: oX 3
2: uM 1
3: uT 2
```

Comment: Terrific! All solutions worked for me? I really appreciate your help guys! Thanks.